# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Distance Matrix send lat and lng but return address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

every one.

you can see this link.
[Google](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix).

this link show parameter variable origin1 and variable destinationB is mean lat and lng.
but i click calculate distances return there address.
i want lat and lng result.
how can?
i need help.
thank you friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of the DistanceMatrixService doesn't contain LatLng's.

When you take a look at the code you'll see that the LatLng's(used to draw the markers) will be requested via geocoding.

Of course you would be able to use the hardcoded LatLng's, but the result may differ, because the locations returned by the DistanceMatrixService must not be equal to these values.

**How to get LatLng's regardless of the input-type(address or LatLng)?**

The geocoding runs asynchronously, there is no guarantee that the results will return in a specific order. Therefore it's not possible to create a string like the demo does.

Instead create DOMNodes(where you want to display the LatLng's), pass these nodes as argument to `addMarker` , and in the geocode-callback set the content of the node to the desired value

```js
var map;
var geocoder;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markersArray = [];

var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930, -3.118);
var origin2 = 'Greenwich, England';
var destinationA = 'Stockholm, Sweden';
var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.087, 14.421);

var destinationIcon = 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-end.png';
var originIcon = 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-start.png';

function initialize() {
  var opts = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.53, 9.4),
    zoom: 10
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), opts);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin1, origin2],
      destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {

  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
    deleteOverlays();

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      //create a new "row"
      var row=outputDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      //origin-marker
      addMarker(origins[i], false,row.appendChild(document.createElement('code')));
      //a list for the destinations
      var list=row.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
      
      
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        var item=list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' to '));
        //destination-marker
        addMarker(destinations[j], true,item.appendChild(document.createElement('code')));
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode([': ',
                                                  results[j].distance.text,
                                                  ' in ',
                                                  results[j].duration.text
                                                  ].join('')));

      }
    }
  }
}

function addMarker(location, isDestination,node) {
  var icon;
  if (isDestination) {
    icon = destinationIcon;
  } else {
    icon = originIcon;
  }
  geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: icon
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
      node.appendChild(document.createTextNode('('+marker.getPosition().toUrlValue()+')'));
      node.setAttribute('title',location);
      node.style.background=(isDestination)?'red':'green';
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(node,'click',function(){map.panTo(marker.getPosition())})
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
        + status);
    }
  });
}

function deleteOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray = [];
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
      }
      #content-pane {
        float:right;
        width:48%;
        padding-left: 2%;
      }

      #outputDiv>div:nth-child(n+2){
         border-top:1px dotted silver;
      }
      #outputDiv code{
        cursor:pointer;
        color:#fff;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&.js"></script>
    <div id="content-pane">
      <button type="button" onclick="calculateDistances();">
        Calculate distances
      </button>
      <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: wow!  thank you. Molle! very good answer! thank you! happy new year!